# watch os2 handoff to iPhone doesn't work when app is being launched

Tags: ios, watchos-2, handoff

i'm having issues with the watch os2 handoff, specially when my iPhone app is not running.
what i see from the launchOptions is:
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey =     {
        UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityIdentifierKey = "xxx";
        UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityTypeKey = "com.xxx";
    };

it seems to be missing the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey that will have the actual NSUserActivity object that i need for handling the handoff.

*when opening it on a running app from the 
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
i do  get the correct NSUserActivity 
and i can handle it properly.

any idea what could have gone wrong?
another thing i have to mention, is when opening core spotlight result on closed app, the NSUserActivity is being passed correctly, so it seems to be an issue only with the watch handoff.